# Finding all records related to selected records in ArcGIS Desktop using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, relates

I have two layers that are related. My current manual process is as follow;

a.  Add the layer 1 to the table of contents

b.  Open the attribute table then Switch selection to select all layer 1 records

c.  Click relates and select layer 2
This will select all layer 2 records related to the layer 1

d.  Switch selection
This will display all layer 2 records not related to the layer 1

e.  Export the table to excel

I want to automate this using ModelBuilder.

This is where I am using ModelBuilder;

Layer 1 > Select Layer By Attribute (Switch selection) > Calculate Field (**I require a python script that is able select all related layer 2 records**) > Select Layer By Attribute (Switch Selection) > Export to Excel

Comment: You want to export records that are in layer 2, and not in layer 1?

Comment: Yes, apologies, should have clarified. However that aspect i can do, its just the 'relates' i am stuck on.

Comment: There is no geo-processing tool in ArcMap that can pass the selection from one table to another. The only way I can think this can be done is with scripting.

Comment: I have come across calculate field and search cursor (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000)
And it has a section to input a python script.

Comment: Yes the use of cursors (which honour selections) is the way to build a list of ID's which you could then use to do a selection with. I've never understood why ESRI have never made a tool to run a relate. Seems like a major omission to me.

Comment: @A.T This script will select unique rows in layer 2: https://jpst.it/1aWPl . Paste in Python window and call function, for example like this: `findunique("Points1","Points2","Id")`

Comment: If you need help with Python then I think you should ask that as a separate question.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your task using Python without the need for relates or joins. Function below will select rows from layer 2 that are not in layer 1 based on a common field. The selection can then be exported to Excel. Let me know if you only want to use ModelBuilder and I will delete my answer.

```
import arcpy

def findunique(layer1, layer2, idfield):
    #Select rows from layer2 that are not in layer1 based on a idfield
    layer1_ids = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer1, idfield)]
    oids_to_select = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer2,['OID@',idfield]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[1] not in layer1_ids:
                oids_to_select.append(row[0])
    sql = """{0} IN ({1})""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(layer2,arcpy.Describe(layer2).OIDFieldName),", ".join(map(str,oids_to_select)))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=layer2, 
                                           where_clause=sql)
```

[image]